# How to show a specific date format in an English view?

Tags: views, datetime

I have multi-language web site. I have a date field with a specific format in a view, and I want to display the date in English format.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you in Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: I'm in **Drupal 7**

Answer (score 0):

In views, click on your date field and select Custom as your `Date format`.

[image]

Then see the [PHP Date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), under `Custom Date Format` type your custom date accordingly.

For Example:

[image]